# Can't see textures outside of texture paint

Tags: texture-painting, object-mode

So I'm trying to paint textures, and I can see them all just fine in the texture paint view, but in object mode in order to be able to see them 
have to
1. Paint the object
2. Right click a different object (which puts me back in object mode)
but if I click back onto the painted object it turns plain white. Has anyone else had this problem? And do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the viewport shading from "solid" to "texture"

[image]

[image]